# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got[XXXX]"

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a Jenkins pipeline that will parse an XML file and return the Nuspec version. I am having issues reading the XML file into a variable without the leading BOM characters (UTF-8), I am now trying to read the file into the variable and add the encoding to use.

I have tried using the following documentation but I keep getting the following error despite many different attempts and different methods of formatting the code.

I have tried following the documentation exactly from here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E84527_01/wcs/tag-ref/JAVA/Utilities_readFile.html

Code:

```
strNuspec = "test.nuspec"
echo 'Reading nuspec into string'
def xml = readFile (String, "${strNuspec}",String, "UTF-8")
println xml
```

and the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [class java.lang.String, test.nuspec, class java.lang.String, UTF-8]

Next:

```
strNuspec = "test.nuspec"
echo 'Reading nuspec into string'
def xml = readFile (strNuspec, "${strNuspec}", encoding, "${encoding}")
println xml
```

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String test.nuspec

This is just a couple of my different attempts at getting this to work. 
I am currently running these commands within this part of my jenkinsfile;

```
stage('Build')  
{  
  steps  
  {  
      script  
     {  
      Code here    
     }  
  }  

}
```

I'm new to groovy but all help is most welcome.

Comment: Also tried the following.                                                                                                 [3]  
`def xml = readFile ("test.nuspec","UTF-8")
 println xml`                                                                                                                    Error message   
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [test.nuspec, UTF-8]`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!!!!!! :D :D :D

```
def encoding = "UTF-8"
strNuspec = "test.nuspec"

def xml = readFile file: "${strNuspec}", encoding: ${encoding}" 
println xml
```

This should also work but I am not 100% sure!
`def xml = readFile file: strNuspec, encoding: encoding`
Hopefully This helps out someone else who comes across the issue!